# Calculate fees before executing an Adaptive Payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm currently creating a website which will act as a marketplace. People can buy and sell stuff and the website takes a commission.

We use the Adaptive Payments API because people are allowed to purchase items of multiple sellers in one transaction and we want it to be set up so that the commission covers the paypal costs.

I read all the docs and I know exactly how PayPal will calculate the fees. The problem is that we can't know in advance how much fees PayPal is going to charge because that depends on which country the seller is based in and more.

My first idea was to create a payment and check the fees, then execute if OK. But even the PaymentDetails API doesn't seem to include information about the fees, although in the "Primary receiver pays all the fees" mode, I would expect to have insight in the fees I have to pay, right ? At best I can only guess the maximum expected fees but I do expect better transparence from a financial institution like PayPal...

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The country doesn't have anything to do with the fees.  It's all based on the monthly volume of the receiver.

- $0 - $3,000 = 2.9% + 30 cents
- $3,000 - $10,000 = 2.5% + 30 cents
- $10,000 - $100,000 = 2.2% + 30 cents
- $100,000+ = 1.9% + 30 cents

The difficult thing is that you won't know what rate any given receiver will be getting unless you somehow know their volume.  You'll need to pick on and calculate it on your own.

The thing is, let's say you have 3 different receivers on the transaction.  Each one could get a different rate.  Maybe 1 is a brand new account so it's at 2.9%, while another is doing $5k/mo in volume so it's at 2.2%, while the 3rd is doing $12k/mo so it would get 2.2%.  Each receiver would pay their fee based the amount they receive and the rate they qualify for.

So again, one way or another you'll just need to calculate this within your app and handle it accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is wrong in numerous ways.

First of all, the country has everything to do with the fees because PayPal has different fees for every country in which the receiver is based, as can be seen on their website (https://cms.paypal.com/ch/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=ua/FeesPolicy_full&locale.x=en_US). In adaptive payments, even if all the fees are paid by the primary receiver, the individual fees are taken into account (based on country/volume/account type )

Plus, I asked how to get the fee amounts precisely, not estimate it like you could have read in my post.

Comment: Ok, well yes, if you make cross-border fees part of the equation that would change things, but it all starts at the base fees I mentioned.  If you want the fees from PayPal, though, you'll need to use IPN or use the GetTransactionDetails API.  Both of those would return the actual fee.